# Connecting Dreamweaver Files Manager with Amazon LightSail

Tags: amazon-web-services, dreamweaver, amazon-lightsail

I've always connected Dreamweaver's file manager to a dedicated server using SFTP, host, username, and password. Is this possible using Amazon Lightsail? If yes, any help is appreciated.

If no, what is the next simplest method?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Great tutorial. It solved my problem. I needed to "switch" the method from username/password to key file. Leave passphrase blank.

https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2017/08/01/aws-connect-to-lightsail-using-sftp-and-panic-transmit/